# Restoring a GPT XFS partition?

Tags: raid, partition, xfs, gpt, parted

I recently added some storage to a RAID array with a single large XFS volume. To expand the volume I normally use parted to remove the partition and then recreate it so that it spans the entire volume.

However, I accidentally removed a partition from /dev/sdb1 instead of /dev/sdb, and cannot seem to restore the partition.

**BEFORE:**

*/dev/sdb* looked something like:

> ```
> (parted) unit s
> (parted) print                                                            
> Model: xxx
> Disk /dev/sdb: 58589705392s
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
> Partition Table: gpt
>
> Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Name  Flags
>  1      2048s    58589705358s  58589703311s  xfs          data
> ```

and,

*/dev/sdb1* looked something like:

> (parted) unit s 
>   (parted) print Model: Unknown (unknown) Disk
>   /dev/sdb1: 58589705392s 
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: loop
>
> Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Flags  1
>   0s     58589705392s  58589705392s  xfs

(sizes might be a little bit off, but other flags like the partition type and filesystem type are accurate)

**AFTER**

After accidentally removing the partition in /dev/sdb1, I tried first recreating it in /dev/sdb1 with no luck, then I tried creating the partition in /dev/sdb using "mkpart primary xfs 2048s -1s", but the filesystem does not show up:

*/dev/sdb* now looks like:

> (parted) unit s
>   (parted) xxx
>   /dev/sdb: 58589705392s 
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>
> Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Name     Flags
>   1      2048s  58589705358s  58589703311s               primary

when I try running parted /dev/sdb1 and looking at things there I get:

> (parted) print 
>   Error: /dev/sdb1: unrecognised disk label

I've tried removing and recreating the partitions in a few different ways, but so far have not been able to restore the original XFS partition so that I can grow it

Any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!